# A thanks message for help

Tags: discussion

This post is just a thank you post for all of you being helpful I'm new to this site and I'm really very very happy and thankful for exchanging interesting information. You are amazing and helpful. I'm really very grateful and thankful to all of you.

Comment: I will break the rules here by acknowledging your message and saying I am glad to be part of this community.

Comment: I’m voting to close this post because it is not a question.

Comment: I echo niels nielson's sentiment.

Comment: @bobD, thanks for that. I too am a recovering ex-engineer/teacher.